# How can I remove a level in a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON in my js script that goes on for another 150 elements :

```
const champlist=[{
    "type": "champion",
    "format": "standAloneComplex",
    "version": "11.10.1",
    "data": {
        "Aatrox": {
            "version": "11.10.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade",
            "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 8,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 3,
                "difficulty": 4
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Aatrox.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": ["Fighter", "Tank"],
            "partype": "Blood Well",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 580,
                "hpperlevel": 90,
                "mp": 0,
                "mpperlevel": 0,
                "movespeed": 345,
                "armor": 38,
                "armorperlevel": 3.25,
                "spellblock": 32,
                "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
                "attackrange": 175,
                "hpregen": 3,
                "hpregenperlevel": 1,
                "mpregen": 0,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0,
                "crit": 0,
                "critperlevel": 0,
                "attackdamage": 60,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 5,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
                "attackspeed": 0.651
            }
        },
        "Ahri": {
            "version": "11.10.1",
            "id": "Ahri",
            "key": "103",
            "name": "Ahri",
            "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox",
            "blurb": "Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 3,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 8,
                "difficulty": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Ahri.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 48,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": ["Mage", "Assassin"],
            "partype": "Mana",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 526,
                "hpperlevel": 92,
                "mp": 418,
                "mpperlevel": 25,
                "movespeed": 330,
                "armor": 21,
                "armorperlevel": 3.5,
                "spellblock": 30,
                "spellblockperlevel": 0.5,
                "attackrange": 550,
                "hpregen": 5.5,
                "hpregenperlevel": 0.6,
                "mpregen": 8,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0.8,
                "crit": 0,
                "critperlevel": 0,
                "attackdamage": 53,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 3,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 2,
                "attackspeed": 0.668
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

But i want it to look like this, with only the "data" part of the JSON and the names removed :

```
[{
            "version": "11.10.1",
            "id": "Aatrox",
            "key": "266",
            "name": "Aatrox",
            "title": "the Darkin Blade",
            "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 8,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 3,
                "difficulty": 4
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Aatrox.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 0,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": ["Fighter", "Tank"],
            "partype": "Blood Well",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 580,
                "hpperlevel": 90,
                "mp": 0,
                "mpperlevel": 0,
                "movespeed": 345,
                "armor": 38,
                "armorperlevel": 3.25,
                "spellblock": 32,
                "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
                "attackrange": 175,
                "hpregen": 3,
                "hpregenperlevel": 1,
                "mpregen": 0,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0,
                "crit": 0,
                "critperlevel": 0,
                "attackdamage": 60,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 5,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
                "attackspeed": 0.651
            },
        {
            "version": "11.10.1",
            "id": "Ahri",
            "key": "103",
            "name": "Ahri",
            "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox",
            "blurb": "Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...",
            "info": {
                "attack": 3,
                "defense": 4,
                "magic": 8,
                "difficulty": 5
            },
            "image": {
                "full": "Ahri.png",
                "sprite": "champion0.png",
                "group": "champion",
                "x": 48,
                "y": 0,
                "w": 48,
                "h": 48
            },
            "tags": ["Mage", "Assassin"],
            "partype": "Mana",
            "stats": {
                "hp": 526,
                "hpperlevel": 92,
                "mp": 418,
                "mpperlevel": 25,
                "movespeed": 330,
                "armor": 21,
                "armorperlevel": 3.5,
                "spellblock": 30,
                "spellblockperlevel": 0.5,
                "attackrange": 550,
                "hpregen": 5.5,
                "hpregenperlevel": 0.6,
                "mpregen": 8,
                "mpregenperlevel": 0.8,
                "crit": 0,
                "critperlevel": 0,
                "attackdamage": 53,
                "attackdamageperlevel": 3,
                "attackspeedperlevel": 2,
                "attackspeed": 0.668
            }
        }
    
];
```

Can anyone help me on how to do this please ? I've been searching all around the internet but every solution doesn't fit exactly my problem.

Comment: `Object.values(champlist[0].data)`

Comment: Maybe something like: *const newlist = [ ...champlist.data ];*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where specifically are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const champs = champList.map(obj => {
    const champ = obj.data
    return Object.values(champ)
})
```

This will return an array for you, you'll need to take champs[0] in order to format the data exactly how you want.